# Clarifying the proof of Theorem 5 in Pratulananda Das's "Some further results on ideal convergence in topological spaces"

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, ideals, proof-explanation

The proof of theorem 5 of [*Some further results on ideal convergence in topological spaces*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2012.04.007) by Pratulananda Das is unclear to me.

> **Theorem 5.** For any sequence $x = (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in a hereditarily Lindelöf space $X$, there exists a sequence $y = (y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $X$ such that $\{n \in\Bbb N: x_n \neq y_n\} \in \mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{I}(C_x) = L(y)$ provided $\mathcal{I}$ satisfies the condition $(AP)$ or in other words is a $P$-ideal.
>
> **Proof.** The proof is finished if $\mathcal{I}(C_x) = L(x)$.

1. How so? It only gives that $I(C_y)=L(y)$. How do we know $L(x)=L(y)$?

> If not then $\mathcal{I}(C_x)\nsubseteq L(x)$.

2. $\mathcal{I}(C_x)\neq L(x)$ if either or both of $\mathcal{I}(C_x)\subset L(x)$ and $L(x)\subset \mathcal{I}(C_x)$ does not hold. So maybe $\mathcal{I}(C_x)\nsubseteq L(x)$ or $L(x)\nsubseteq \mathcal{I}(C_x)$. How does he know it's the first one?

> For each $z ∈ L(x)\setminus \mathcal{I}(C_x)$ we can find an open set $U_z$ containing $z$ such that $\{n \in \mathbb N: x_n \in U_z\} \in \mathcal{I}$.

3. Even if $\mathcal{I}(C_x)\nsubseteq L(x)$, how can we say $z\in L(x)\setminus\mathcal{I}(C_x)$? Because $\mathcal{I}(C_x)\nsubseteq L(x)\implies \mathcal{I}(C_x)\setminus L(x)\neq \varnothing$ and not $L(x)\setminus\mathcal{I}(C_x)\neq \varnothing$ because $\mathcal{I}(C_x)\nsubseteq L(x)$ holds when $\mathcal{I}(C_x)$ is a proper superset of $L(x)$ and in that case $L(x)\setminus\mathcal{I}(C_x)=\varnothing$ and we shall find no $z\in L(x)\setminus\mathcal{I}(C_x)$

> Now $\{U_z: z \in L(x)\setminus \mathcal{I}(C_x)\}$ forms an open cover of $L(x)\setminus\mathcal{I}(C_x)$ and so it has a countable subcover $\{U_{z_i}: i \in \mathbb N\}$ (say). Put $A_i = \{n \in \mathbb N: x_n \in U_{z_i}\}$. Then $(A_i)$ is a sequence of sets in $\mathcal{I}$ and since $\mathcal{I}$ has property (AP), there exists an $A \in\mathcal I$ such that $A_i\setminus A$ is finite for each $i$. If $\mathbb N\setminus A = \{k_n: n \in \mathbb N\}$, then construct $y = (y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ as
>   follows:
>
> $$\begin{cases}
> y_n=x_{k_n}&\text{if }n\in A,\\
> y_n=x_n&\text{if }n\notin A.
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Clearly then $\{n \in \mathbb N: x_n \neq y_n\} \subset A$ and so belongs to $\mathcal I$. By Theorem 4 we have $\mathcal{I}(C_x) = \mathcal{I}(C_y)$. But note that the subsequence $(x_{k_n} )$ of $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has no accumulation point in $L(x)\setminus \mathcal{I}(C_x)$ and so has no $\mathcal{I}$-limit point of $(y_n)$ (since $\mathcal I$ is admissible).

4. I cannot see at all how it follows that if the subsequence $(x_{k_n} )$ of $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has no accumulation point in $L(x)\setminus \mathcal{I}(C_x)$, then it has no $\mathcal{I}$-limit point of $(y_n)$.

> So $L(y) = \mathcal{I}(C_y)$ and consequently we have $L(y) = \mathcal{I}(C_x)$. $\square$

### Necessary definitions and statements

In the following $X$ is a topological space, $\mathcal{I}$ is an ideal on $\mathbb N$, $x = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence in $X$.

- $y \in X$ is called an *$\mathcal{I}$-limit point* of $x$ if there is a strictly increasing sequence $( m_k )_{k \in \mathbb N}$ in $\mathbb N$ such that $\{ m_k : k \in \mathbb N \} \notin \mathcal{I}$ and $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_{m_k} = y$.
- $y \in X$ is called an *$\mathcal{I}$-cluster point* of $x$ if for every open set $U$ containing $y$, $\{n \in N: x_n \in U\}\notin\mathcal{I}$. And the collection of all $\mathcal{I}$-cluster points of $X$ is denoted by $\mathcal{I}(C_x)$.
- $z\in L(x)$ if for each neighborhood $W$ of $z$, $\{n \in \mathbb N: x_n \in W \}$ is infinite (i.e., $L(x)$ is the set of all cluster points of $x$).
- $\mathcal{I}$ has *property (AP)* (or is a *P-ideal*) if for every sequence $( A_n )_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in $\mathcal I$ there exists an $A_\infty \in \mathcal I$ such that $A_n \setminus A_\infty$ is a finite set for every $n \in \mathbb N$.
- $\mathcal{I}$ is *admissible* (or *free*) if it contains all singletons.
- **Theorem 4.** If $x = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $y = (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ are two sequences in $X$ such that $\{ n \in \mathbb N : x_n \neq y_n \} \in   \mathcal I$, then $\mathcal{I} ( C_x) = \mathcal{I} ( C_y )$.
  *(The paper actually states "... $\{ n \in \mathbb N : x_n \neq y_n \} \notin   \mathcal I$ ...", however following the proof this is clearly a typo.)*

Comment: Answers will probably depend on what $I(C_x)$ means --- perhaps the ideal obtained by adjoining $C_x$ to $I$, or perhaps the ideal obtained by restricting $C_x$ to $I$ --- and therefore depend also on what $C_x$ means.  If you supplied those definitions, you might get an answer from someone who can explain the problem but doesn't want to take the time to get the paper and seek out the relevant definitions.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: OMG, you could have just suggested mentioning those definitions here. But why  make the wild guess about $I(C_x)?$ That's ridiculous. And also the people who I know are capable of answering this do not need to go to the paper, they know what those things are and also I've added proper citation. But thanks anyway.

Comment: If you want someone to verify a proof that *you* wrote, use [proof-verification], otherwise don't; if you want someone to help you with the writing of *your* proof, use [proof-writing], otherwise don't; if you want someone to explain to you someone else's proof, use [proof-explanation], otherwise don't.

Comment: @user118494: I don’t know about Martin Sleziak, but ***I*** certainly had to go to the paper to answer one of your earlier question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: You mean you had to *go to the paper* to take a look at which one that was ,right? Not that you had to go through it like reading for the first time. That's different from what AndreassBlass means , he/she is not familiar with this topic apparently, judging from his comment.

Comment: @user118494: No, I mean that it was wholly unfamiliar to me. I was seeing it for the first time, and while I have on rare occasions dealt with filter convergence, I had never seen ideal convergence. And I have very, very little doubt that anything along these lines that I can do, Andreas Blass can do at least as well.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Ok,sorry, my bad. But it still doesn't change the fact that AndreasBals's comment with that *wild guess* is ridiculous. BTW, I thought you guys already knew everything that I could ask. But anyways, it's just as good. (Off-topic : Do you and Mr. Sleziak know each other in real life?)

Comment: @user118494 A more constructive approach than adding comments why you did not include the definitions would be add them to the question. This helps potential answerers. and it is not much work for you, since you had several questions about $\mathcal I$-cluster points and similar topics recently. You can either copy the definitions between the posts or simply add something link: The definitions of these notions are given in this post (followed by a link). Here I have edit your post to add the definitions (which are definitely not known to everybody), please do check whether my edit was correct.

Comment: And, if I may comment on this particular (for the lack of better word) incident, you might consider yourself lucky that users such as [Andreas Blass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_Blass) (which is one of the world leading experts in set theory) and Brian M. Scoot (whom I consider one of the best experts on general topology brightest users on this site - judging by his contributions I have seen so far) took interest in your question. So if they are asking for a clarification, it's better simply to explain what's need rather than add comments which might alienate them.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Sir, my comment to AndreasBells was not any excuse to not adding definitions,which is why I thanked him/her, and right after that I had edited my post to add the definitions though, under the heading **necessary definitions** near the end of the post. I just pointed a finger to his *guess*,that's all.  And your edit is perfectly correct Sir.

Comment: @user118494 My mistake. (The only excuse that I did not notice that you in fact *included those definition* is that is it 6 A.M. in my timezone. I cannot thing of some more plausible excuse.) Feel free to remove the parts I have added or if you think that they add some useful stuff to the definitions you have already added, then perhaps you can edited them somehow to put them together. (Or, of course, if you are satisfied with the way the post looks at the moment, you can simply leave this version.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Not at all removing them. As for Mr. Blass and Mr. Scott, if you think my comments  have somehow offended(which was absolutely not my intention,may be my wordings somehow and I'm not  fluent in this language) them in any way , I'll apologize to them separately.Putting anybody off my posts would be the last thing in my mind.

Comment: @AndreasBlass : Sir, please accept my apology if my comment has , in any way, gave you any kind of bad feeling. That was so not my intention.I in fact edited my question after your comment but unfortunately did not mention that in my comment.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:Sir, please accept my apology if my comments have , in any way, given you any kind of bad feeling. That was not my intention  at all.

Comment: @user118494 This is to some extent more my fault then yours. I would consider your response to Andreas Blass impolite, if you posted such comment *without* adding the relevant definitions to the question. And I simply overlooked that you have indeed added them. In any case, we have digressed far from the topic of the question. If needed, we can continue this discussion [here in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2016/10/27).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything I am doing in this answer is under the assumption that the ideal $\mathcal I$ is admissible.

> 1. How so? It only gives that $\mathcal I(C_y)=L(y)$. How do we know $L(x)=L(y)$?

We want to show that *there exists* $y$ such that $\mathcal I(C_x)=L(y)$. If $I(C_x)=L(x)$, then we can simply choose $y=x$.

> 2. How does he know it's the first one?

This is clarified here: [What is the usual relationship between $L(x)$ and $I(C_x)\ ?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987108/what-is-the-usual-relationship-between-lx-and-ic-x)

We can show that for an admissible ideal we have $\mathcal I(C_x)\subseteq L(x)$. So if the two sets are different, then $L(x)\nsubseteq \mathcal I(C_x)$. (The proof in the paper writes it in the opposite way, which is a typo.) And we have in such case that $L(x)\setminus \mathcal I(C_x)\ne\emptyset$.

> 3. How can we say $z\in L(x)\setminus\mathcal{I}(C_x)$?

In this part of the proof the author is going to show that something holds for every such $z$. So, naturally, the proof starts with assuming that $z\in L(x)\setminus \mathcal I(C_x)$. Then they get existence of $U_z$ with the properties described in the proof for each $z\in L(x)\setminus\mathcal{I}(C_x)$.

> 4. I cannot see at all how it follows that if the subsequence $(x_{k_n})$ of $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has no accumulation point in $L(x)\setminus \mathcal{I}(C_x)$, then it has no $\mathcal{I}$-limit point of $(y_n)$.

Let us try to repeat the last part of the proof it detail so that we clearly see all necessary components of the proof.

We have an open over $\{U_{z_i}; i\in\mathbb N\}$ of $L(x)\setminus \mathcal I(C_x)$. For each $i$ we denote $A_i=\{n\in\mathbb N; x_n\in U_{z_i}\}$. Using the fact that $\mathcal I$ is P-ideal we get a set $A\in\mathcal I$ such that each $A_i\setminus A$ is finite.

Then we denote $\mathbb N \setminus A=\{k_1<k_2<\dots<k_n<\dots\}$ and we define
$$
y_n=
  \begin{cases}
    x_{k_n} & \text{if }n\in A, \\
    x_n & \text{of }n\notin A.
  \end{cases}
$$
Since the sequence $x$ and $y$ differ only on the set $A$ which belongs to the ideal $\mathcal I$, we get that $\mathcal I(C_x)=\mathcal I(C_y)$.

We want to prove that $L(y)=\mathcal I(C_x)$. We will do this in several steps.

> **Observation 1.** $L(y)\subseteq L(x)$.

If some subsequence of $y$ converges to $z$, then we can get either subsequence of $x_n$ or subsequence of $x_{k_n}$ which converges to $z$. In either case $z\in L(x)$.

> **Observation 2.** For each $i$ the set $\{n\in \mathbb N; x_{k_n}\in U_{z_i}\}$ is finite.

If $x_{k_n}\in U_{z_i}$, then $k_n\in A_i \cap (\mathbb N\setminus A)= A_i\setminus A$. So there is only finitely many such $k_n$'s. And since $n\mapsto k_n$ is bijective, we also have only finitely many $n$'s.

> **Observation 3.** For each $i$ the set $\{n\in\mathbb N; y_n\in U_{z_i}\}$ is finite.

We have
$$\{n\in\mathbb N; x_n\in U_{z_i}\} \subseteq \{n\in\mathbb N; x_{k_n}\in U_{z_i}\} \cup (\{n\in\mathbb N; n\in U_{z_i}\}\cap(\mathbb N\setminus A)).$$
The first set is finite by Observation 2. The second one is precisely $A_i\setminus A$, which is finite too.

(Notice that this really implies that: "$(x_{k_n})$ of $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has no accumulation point in $L(x)\setminus \mathcal{I}(C_x)$" (as claimed in the paper). However, for me the proof seemed to be a bit clearer when I formulated it as above.)

> **Observation 4.** $L(y)\cap (L(x)\setminus\mathcal I(C_x))=\emptyset$.

If $z\in L(x)\setminus\mathcal I(C_x)$, then there is some $i\in\mathbb N$ such that $z\in U_{z_i}$. (Here we are using simply the fact that $\{U_{z_i}; i\in\mathbb N\}$ is covering of $L(x)\setminus\mathcal I(C_x)$.)

Then by observation 3 we have only finitely many terms of the sequence $y$ in this neighborhood of $z$ and therefore $z$ is not a cluster point of $y$.

**Conclusion.**
From $L(y)\subseteq L(x)$ and $L(y)\cap (L(x)\setminus\mathcal I(C_x))=\emptyset$ we get that
$$L(y) \subseteq \mathcal I(C_x).$$
We also know that $$\mathcal I(C_y)\subseteq L(y)$$
since $\mathcal I$ is admissible ideal. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987108/what-is-the-usual-relationship-between-lx-and-ic-x).)

Using this, together with the fact that $\mathcal I(C_y)=\mathcal I(C_x)$, we get
$$\mathcal I(C_y) \subseteq L(y)\subseteq \mathcal I(C_x)=\mathcal I(C_y)$$
which means that all these sets are equal to each other. In particular, we get
$$L(y)=\mathcal I(C_x).$$

---

It is probably worth mentioning that this results is a generalization of Theorem 2 from the paper J. A. Fridy: *Statistical limit points,* Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 118 (1993), 1187-1192; https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1993-1181163-6 http://www.jstor.org/stable/2160076 In this paper the same result is shown for the ideal of sets having asymptotic density zero. The proof of the more general result seems to be along the same lints as Fridy's proof of the special case.