# What is the usual relationship between $L(x)$ and $I(C_x)\ ?$

Tags: general-topology, ideals, proof-explanation

$X$ is a topological space. and $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb N.$ $x=\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence of elements in $X.$

The following two definitions:

$L(x):x\in L(x) \text{ if for every neighbourhood }W \text{ of }z,\{n\in \mathbb N: x_n\in W\}\text{ is infinite. }$

$I(C_x)=\left\{z\in X:\text{ for every neighbourhood }U \text{ of }z,\{n\in \mathbb N:x_n\in U\}\notin I\right\}$

Now my question is what is the inclusive relationship between them? That is whether $I(C_x)\subset L(x)$ or $L(x)\subset I(C_x)?$

If I take any point from $W$, say $y$ and a nbd $U$ of $y$ , then the set $\{n\in \mathbb N: x_n\in W\}$ is infinite but that does not tell whether it is in $I$ or not for both $I$ and $F(I)$  can contain infinite sets.So $L(x)\nsubseteq I(C_x).$

Then it must be the other way round.Take $z\in I(C_x)$ and any nbd $U$ of $z.$ Then $\{n\in \mathbb N:x_n\in U\}\notin I.$ Had they said $I$ is admissible i.e. containing all the singletons then we could conclude from here that *since all finite sets are in $I$, this **'necessarily outside of $I$'** set must be infinite and hence $I(C_x)\subset L(x)$* but not such thing is said in [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0166864112001812/1-s2.0-S0166864112001812-main.pdf?_tid=0764b42e-9bfb-11e6-96a8-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1477541494_27d71e696acb265915d8da77d6fc7034)
***Some further results on ideal convergence in topological spaces*** by
*Pratulananda Das*.

But in the proof of **theorem $5$** something of this sort has been used and I do not understand exactly what he has done. Please help me understand this. Thank a lot. Or is there some typo in the proof and some modification required, like a couple of cases before?

Comment: In the case $X=\mathbb R$: It should be relatively easy to see that every limit point is an I-limit point (assuming we are working with admissible ideals). (Just notice that $L(x)$ contains precisely the limits of subsequences of $x$.) And every I-limit point is an I-cluster point. When I have more time, I'll try to think a bit in more detail whether something changes if we are working with arbitrary topological spaces. And perhaps post an answer if I am able to say something useful about this. (But at least in metric spaces, the same argument as for $X=\mathbb R$ should work.)

Comment: Ok, so now I see that I probably wrote the implication in my previous comment the other way round, so the above is not true. And, in addition to that, it is not relevant for this problem, since here we are working with I-cluster points and not I-limit points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider a sequence $(x_n)$ as a function $x \colon \mathbb N \to X$. This can simplify notation a bit, since we can write simply $x^{-1}(U)$ instead of the longer notation $\{n\in\mathbb N; x_n\in U\}$.

Let us denote by $\newcommand{\Fin}{\mathrm{Fin}}\Fin$ the ideal of finite sets.

So we now have
\begin{align*}
z\in I(C_x) &\Leftrightarrow \text{for each neighborhood $U$ of $z$ we have } x^{-1}(U) \notin I\\
z\in L(x) &\Leftrightarrow \text{for each neighborhood $U$ of $z$ we have } x^{-1}(U) \notin \Fin
\end{align*}

If $I$ is admissible ideal, then $\Fin\subseteq I$ and therefore
$$x^{-1}(U) \notin I \implies x^{-1}(U) \notin \Fin.$$

So we get that $I(C_x)\subseteq L(x)$.

---

If the ideal $I$ is not admissible, the same claim is not true. Simply choose some integer $n_0$ and take $I=\{A\subseteq\mathbb N; n_0\notin A\}$. Then the only $I$-cluster point (and at the same time $I$-limit) of a sequence $x$ is equal to $x_{n_0}$. And it is easy to find a sequence such that $L(x)\ne\{x_{n_0}\}$.

Comment: So this won't work without the  *admissible* criterion?.I actually had this in my very post. that had it been *admissible* then $I(C_x)\subset L(x)$ would hold but I did not see *admissible* mentioned in the particular theorem.

Comment: However the author mentions in the proof that $\mathcal I$ is admissible, so he probably wanted to work with admissible ideals only. (With is rather common assumption.)

Comment: Yes, that must be the case.